# Custom dropdown search form that allows users to select option B based from Option 1

Tags: customization, taxonomy, search, forms, dropdown

I'm trying to create a search form (currently using Search & Filter) that has a dropdown for states and categories,  and once a state is selected I want another dropdown to open allowing visitors to choose a city in that state. I don't know what to use (taxonomies, post types, categories, tags??)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Metabox with Taxonomy Dropdown - Saving Issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/custom-metabox-with-taxonomy-dropdown-saving-issue)

Answer (score 0):

There should be sub taxonomy under your main taxonomy that is in your case states taxonomy.

P.S categories and tags are part of the taxonomy...